# GlassFish not loading connector

Tags: mysql, connection, glassfish, classpath, pool

I'm using GlassFish 3 and I can't seem to get it to recognize the MySql connector. The admin console always says:

> Ping Connection Pool for --- is
>   Failed. Ping failed Exception - Class
>   name is wrong or classpath is not set
>   for :
>   com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource
>   Please check the server.log for more
>   details.

However, JPA can connect even with the error. The only downside is that I get resize pool exceptions (null). I've even placed the connector in the following folders:

- %GLASSFISH%/lib
- %GLASSFISH%/domains/domain1/lib
- %GLASSFISH%/domains/domain1/lib/ext

I also tried the solution at http://old.nabble.com/MySql-connector-problems,-Class-name-is-wrong-or-classpath-td21833176.html however setting class path is (unsupported in V3).

Any ideas? :(

EDIT:

Nvm... I fixed it by dropping the connector in

> eclipse/plugins/oracle.eclipse.runtime.glassfish_3.1.0.0/glassfish3/glassfish/lib

Comment: The fix that worked for you, worked for me as well! Thank you so much, I never would have thought to put it there. All other tutorials say to put it in the domains lib folder, if you're on a mac, try it this way if you've run out of ideas! Slightly different note, if you've just created a MySQL user, make sure you restart the MySQL server before trying to ping with that user, otherwise it won't find it!